# How to get entire friend list from Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, graph

Technically I have two questions:

> **1st** - Is there any way to get Facebook access, through an account, without having to create a Facebook App ?? Like having an account access token instead of an App token.
>
> **2nd** - Through Facebook Graph API can I get my friends list ? I use the permission "user_friends" and I request"me/friendlist" and I only get 3 friends out of more than 400 on my friends list.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) No, without any App you can´t get Access to anything. Even the most simple Access Token needs an App: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens

2) Since April 2014, you can only get the friends who authorized the App too, for privacy reasons: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

Comment: I wanted to make a C# program which reads my friends list to see their status updates and read their education history. Are you telling me that's not possible through an API, even though I can read it through facebook's web client ?

Comment: that is not possible at all, since friend permissions are deprecated. available through web client does not mean you can grab everything with the api. it´s pretty limited for privacy reasons.

Comment: Well that sucks. Thanks.